# When to use saveAndFlush in springs SimpleJpaRepository?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring-data-jpa `interface CrudRepository` to save large data sets in a database on a daily batch import.

```
@Bean
public ItemWriter<MyEntity> jpaItemWriter() {
    RepositoryItemWriter<MyEntity> writer = new RepositoryItemWriter<>();
    writer.setRepository(repository);
    writer.setMethodName("save");
    return writer;
}
```

The default implementation for this interface is `SimpleJpaRepository`, which offers a `saveAndFlush()` method. What is that for? Would this method be any help for me, eg regarding performance, if I run this method rather than `save()`?

Answer (score 11):

One example would be if you were using Optimistic Locking and wanted to explicitly catch an OptimisticLockException and throw it back to the client. If the changes are only flushed to the database on transaction commit (i.e. when your transactional method returns) then you cannot do so. Explicity flushing from within your transactional method allows you to catch and rethrow/handle.

From the JPA Specification:

> 3.4.5 OptimisticLockException Provider implementations may defer writing to the database until the end of the transaction, when
>   consistent with the lock mode and flush mode settings in effect. In
>   this case, an optimistic lock check may not occur until commit time,
>   and the OptimisticLockException may be thrown in the "before
>   completion" phase of the commit. **If the OptimisticLockException must
>   be caught or handled by the application, the flush method should be
>   used by the application to force the database writes to occur**. This
>   will allow the application to catch and handle optimistic lock
>   exceptions

So, in answer to your question, it is not performance related but there may be cases when you want to explicitly flush to the database from within a transactional method.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Spring Data's Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.1.RELEASE/api/), `saveAndFlush`:

> Saves an entity and flushes changes instantly.

if you using `save` method, it flushes changes when the underlying transaction commits.